# Database modelled role based security in Pyramid

Tags: pyramid

I want to implement role based security (RBAC) where

users -> roles -> priviledges

are stored in the database in the attached ERD.

How can I actually convert the priviledges (read in via SQL) into actual permissions for ACLs to secure resources

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I worked on my last Pyramid project, but I did have a basic ACL setup with a database back-end that protected my views.  Hopefully this might help?  I'm pretty sure I fumbled my way through the [Pyramid security docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html) and [authorization](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki/authorization.html) to get something working.

I had in my `RootFactory` class a definition of my ACLs:

```
class RootFactory(object):
    ''' ACLs are set up in a cumulative manner

        On a given view, set the permission to the minimum level of access that can request that object.
        Given the ACLs, a user set in one level should have access to all levels below, too.
    '''
    __acl__ = [
        (Allow, Everyone, 'view'),
        (Allow, Authenticated, 'edit'),
        (Allow, 'reportviewer', ('reportviewer')),
        (Allow, 'clientuser', ('reportviewer', 'clientuser')),
        (Allow, 'clientadmin', ('reportviewer', 'clientuser', 'clientadmin')),
        (Allow, 'trialuser', ('reportviewer', 'clientuser', 'clientadmin')),
        (Allow, 'siteuser', ('reportviewer', 'clientuser', 'clientadmin', 'siteuser')),
        (Allow, 'siteadmin', ('reportviewer', 'clientuser', 'clientadmin', 'siteuser', 'siteadmin'))
    ]

    def __init__(self, request):
        pass
```

Then on my views I would give assign them a permission:

```
@view_config(route_name='useredit', renderer='useredit.mako', permission='siteadmin')
```

My `groupfinder` returned the roles that the current user belonged to:

```
def groupfinder(userid, request):
    user = DBSession.query(User).filter(User.id == userid).first()
    return [g.name for g in user.roles]
```

Roles were just a relationship table that I added to my User class object for easier access.  Everything was using SQLAlchemy as the ORM.

```
UserRole = Table('roles_users', Base.metadata,
                  Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"),
                         primary_key=True),
                  Column('role_id', Integer, ForeignKey("roles.id"),
                         primary_key=True))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(Text, unique=True)
    displayname = Column(Text)

    roles = relationship("Role", secondary=UserRole)
```

Comment: `__acl__`  can also be dynamic. Here is an example: http://websauna.org/docs/narrative/crud/standalone.html?highlight=contract#creating-crud-resources